# Appsync GraphQL with "None" data source trying to pass through a list of return items

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I have an AppSync API that I'm using for an app. One action I'm trying to do is have a Lambda function that collects certain data fire off a GraphQL mutation, and then have a subscription on my front end collect that data when the mutation is called. This data is ephemeral and I don't want to write it to a database, so I'm trying to set up a "None" data source in AppSync just to pass this data off.

I have an AppSync GraphQL API set up with the following (simplified) schema:

```
type Mutation @aws_api_key
@aws_cognito_user_pools {
    sendSearchResults(input: SearchResultInputHeader!): SearchResultOutputHeader
}

input SearchResultInput {
    assetId: String
    score: Float
}

input SearchResultInputHeader {
    callId: String
    results: [SearchResultInput]
}

type SearchResultOutput @aws_api_key
@aws_cognito_user_pools {
    assetId: String
    score: Float
}

type SearchResultOutputHeader @aws_api_key
@aws_cognito_user_pools {
    callId: String
    results: [SearchResultOutput]
}
```

and the following request / response resolver mappings:

```
// REQUEST::
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "payload": {
        "callId": "${context.arguments.input.callId}",
        "results": "${context.arguments.input.results}"
    }
}

// RESPONSE::
$util.toJson($context.result)
```

I am able to pass the `callId` String through this mutation but I am unable to get the `results` to pass through

```
// INPUT::
mutation MyMutation {
  sendSearchResults(input: {resultsIn: [{assetId: "0001", score: 10}, {assetId: "0002", score: 22}], callId: "aaa-aaa-aaa"}) {
    callId
    resultsOut {
      assetId
    }
  }
}

// RETURN::
{
  "data": {
    "sendSearchResults": {
      "callId": "aaa-aaa-aaa",
      "resultsOut": null
    }
  }
}
```

So I have two main questions:

1. How can I get the resolver/mutation to return a list of results rather than `null`?
2. Any other suggestions on passing data through an AppSync mutation and subscription? Or does this approach seem to make sense without writing to a database and just receiving a key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

// REQUEST::

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "payload": {
        "callId": "${context.arguments.input.callId}",
        "results": "${context.arguments.input.results}"
    }
}
```

// INPUT::

```
mutation MyMutation {
  sendSearchResults(input: {resultsIn: [{assetId: "0001", score: 10}, {assetId: "0002", score: 22}], callId: "aaa-aaa-aaa"}) {
    callId
    resultsOut {
      assetId
    }
  }
}
```

Here is results and resultsIn are different is two places.